# How would I make a grid of images on a webpage sortable?

Tags: php, javascript, image, html

I'd like to set up a grid of images on a webpage, and have them sortable via categories that would be selected by a menu.

Preferably this would be done without ever refeshing the entire page, and done without javascript or jquery.

For example, there might be 12 images, sorted into four categories.  The menu would consist of "Category 1," "Category 2," etc.  By clicking on one of these options the images below would simply be rearranged with the selected categorized images at the top.

Is there a simple php script that could accomplish this?  Would it involve setting the images in various arrays?

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, you won't be able to change the order without either a) using a client-side language like javascript (jQuery) or b) refreshing the page. So take your pick

Comment: What have you tried? We're very willing to help on SO, but only if you've shown actual effort in researching or trying something.

Comment: I haven't tried anything insofar as coding because I don't know JS.  I've created php arrays in the past but they've all involved refreshing the page and I wouldn't know where to begin alleviating that.  I've done a hundred google/forum searches for a solution with no luck, and I've tried integrating various grid based image rotators but they never look right and seem like a rather cumbersome "solution."

Comment: It is surprising that there wouldn't be a simpler way to re-sort separate elements on a webpage with a single click.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it is possible to do this without refreshing the page AND without using JavaScript. Here's how it works (just a minimal example):

Create an `iframe` in your HTML page. The `iframe` will display the menu as well as the sorted images.

```
<iframe src="content.php" width="300" height="100" border="1"></iframe>
```

Then in `content.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="content.php">
<select name="select">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["select"])) {
    // sort images however you want and echo them
    echo "Option ".$_POST["select"];
}
?>
```

So when submitting the form, only the `iframe` is reloaded (and not the entire page).

Note that this is no more than a workaround. What you're trying to achieve really shouldn't be done like that. JavaScript would definitely be the better choice.